# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'catalog_product_entity_varchar.ebay_template_new' in 'field list'

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

I have migrated data from Magento CE 1.9.2.0 to CE 2.2.5

Migration is successfully for data of old Magento 1 to latest Magento 2 version.

 **While I am trying to save the product from admin or programmatically Bellow error generated**

**Error :**

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'catalog_product_entity_varchar.ebay_template_new' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `catalog_product_entity_varchar`.`ebay_template_new` FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` WHERE (ebay_template_new LIKE :attribute_code) ORDER BY `entity_id` DESC, `ebay_template_new` ASC LIMIT 1

Anyone please help to resolve error..!

Comment: After migrate you have also installed third party module like ebay, m2pro?

Comment: First Installed m2pro and then migrate data

Comment: create column manuaaly or Remove module and again try to install so that create column in table.